# Pandas/regex based approach to match first string from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Apologies if this is cross-listed; I searched for a while!

I'm working with some very large, very messy data in Pandas. The variable of interest is a string, and contains one or more instances of business names with(out) typical business suffixes (e.g., LLC, LP, LTD). For example, I might have "ABC LLC XYZ,LLC XYZ, LTD". My goal is to find the first instance of a suffix, matched from a list. I also need to extract everything up to this first match. For the above example, I'd except to find/extract "ABC LLC". Consider the following data:

```
 sfx = ['LLC','LP','LTD']
 dat = pd.DataFrame({'name':['ABC LLC XYZ,LLC XYZ, LTD','IJK LP, ADDRESS']})
```

So far, I've accomplished this for a single case in a convoluted way that isn't working for me:

```
one_string = 'ABC LLC XYZ,LLC XYZ, LTD'
indexes=[]
keywords=dict()
for sf in sfx:
    indexes.append(one_string.index(sf,0))
    keywords[one_string.index(sf,0)]=sf
    indexes.sort()
    print(one_string[0:indexes[0]]+ keywords[indexes[0]])
```

I'm looking for a more efficient (possibly vectorized) way of doing this for an entire column. In addition, I need to incorporate regex in order to avoid extracting suffixes when the same letter combinations just happen to appear in the text. The regex pattern I need to match might look something like this (LLC appears after space or comma and is at the end of a word):

```
reg_pattern = r`(?<=[\s\,])LLC\b|(?<=[\s\,])LP\b|(?<=[\s\,])LTD\b`
```

**UPDATE**

Straightforward solution by Wiktor. I also realized once I have extract what precedes the suffix, I will then need to extract everything that comes after it separately. Throwing the solution into a positive look behind didn't work. Very appreciative!

Comment: Use `pattern = r"^(.*?\b(?:{}))(?!\w)".format("|".join(map(re.escape, names)))` and then `df['results'] = df['texts'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)` (adjust the column names)

Comment: Thx @WiktorStribiżew! How could I edit this to now only extract what comes *after* the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the texts that come before and including the keywords, you may use

```
pattern = r"^(.*?\b(?:{}))(?!\w)".format("|".join(map(re.escape, names)))
```

and then

```
df['results'] = df['texts'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
```

Adjust the column names to match your code. The pattern will look like `^(.*?\b(?:LLC|LP|LTD))(?!\w)` and will mean:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?\b(?:LLC|LP|LTD))` - Group 1 (this value will be returned by `.str.extract`):

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?:LLC|LP|LTD)` - one of the alternatives: `LLC`, `LP` or `LTD`
- `(?!\w)` - not followed with a word char: letter, digit or `_`.

To get all text after a match, you may use

```
pattern = r"\b(?:{})(?!\w)(.*)".format("|".join(map(re.escape, names)))
```

Here, the pattern will look like `\b(?:LLC|LP|LTD))(?!\w)(.*)` and it first matches one of the names as a whole word, and then captures into Group 1 all the rest of the line (matched with `(.*)` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars).